# Place 2+ Textfields side-by-side in a LinearLayout (horizontal) programmatically

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

i know, there are a lot of questions like this. I read a lot on stackoverflow and google about this topic, but nothing help me :(

Ok, here is the problem. I have a small app. In this app i have a fragment. The layout.xml for this fragment includes a placeholder linearlayout like the following

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/placeholderLinLayout">
        </LinearLayout>
```

The fragment has a button. If u click on it a DialogFragmentPopup opens and u can enter some data-stuff. After you enter the data you can click on another button on this dialog and the data will be transfere to the main-fragment. Here i call a method which should generate programmatically a layout to present the data. I use the following code

```
            myRoot = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.placeholderLinLayout);
            innerLayout = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
            innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            innerLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            LinearLayout productHeaderLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            productHeaderLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            productHeaderLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            TextView product_header = new TextView(getContext());
            product_header.setText("Produkt");
            product_header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            TextView amount_header = new TextView(getContext());
            amount_header.setText("Menge");
            amount_header.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            amount_header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            TextView packaging_header = new TextView(getContext());
            packaging_header.setText("Verpackung");
            packaging_header.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            packaging_header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            TextView price_header = new TextView(getContext());
            price_header.setText("Preis");
            price_header.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            price_header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            TextView payment_header = new TextView(getContext());
            payment_header.setText("Zahlart");
            payment_header.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            payment_header.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            productHeaderLayout.addView(product_header);
            productHeaderLayout.addView(amount_header);
            productHeaderLayout.addView(packaging_header);
            productHeaderLayout.addView(price_header);
            productHeaderLayout.addView(payment_header);

            innerLayout.addView(productHeaderLayout);
```

The problem is, that the first textview push all other textviews out of the visible space, see the screenshot

[image]

What i want to do is, that these 5 textviews spread out automatically to the existing width. I googled a lot and the code i post here is the result of which i found many times on the internet.

So i hope someone can help find out the problem in my code :)

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set all your TextView layout paramters to this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
```

And remove `.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);` from all the TextViews.

This will guarantee that all the views will have same weight set to them, and that weight gives all the views in LinearLayout same Width (or Height if orientation is set to vertical).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your setting the TextView to `MATCH_PARENT` in its width. So one TextView takes the whole screen and the other starts just out of it. To solve this set the layoutparam width to `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Better yet, if you want to spread it, you can use the LinearLayout's weight property so they take as much space as they can:

```
textview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));
```

The third parameter `1f` is the weight. A weight of one means it'll take all the available space without intruding on the other children, hence they will all spread evenly.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have your TextViews side by side, you must set the orientation of the LinearLayout to `horizontal` instead of `vertical`